# Datatable grouping to perform aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, grouping, aggregate

I'm trying to create a extension method for `DataTable` to perform grouping like we do in `SQL Server`, where I'll pass the group by columns and aggregate functions of columns and it will return a new `DataTable` based on grouping. Now All of you will obviously ask me to use `LINQ` but the problem is that the total `DataTable` is dynamic and there is a user interface where user can change the grouping. Now writing a static linq is not possible. How can I achieve this to dynamically let user perform any aggregation on a `DataTable`. Can any one shed some idea.

Comment: Look at the [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Comment: how come this can't be done using `Sql Server along with a stored procdure`

Comment: The extension method `QueryByCube` implemented by the component [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) can help you. (discaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer)

Comment: @nlips Can you provide an example.